# Return Object from function in dll

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

There is a library that implements this function:

```c
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int Material() //want to replase int
{
    IMaterial** Materials = new IMaterial*(); //Abstract class
    IMaterial* Material = Materials[0];
}
```

In NET code I want to return like this:

```c
object[] = Material()
```

How to change the code CPP so that it returns

```c
Materials [0]
```

Comment: That code makes no sense, why would you return an uninitialized and unallocated pointer?

Comment: Materials [0] will be used in the NET code. I'm new to cpp. My goal is to separate and cpp NET code into several pieces (why - that is another question.)
here [link](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.irendermaterial~addentity.html)
I need to get in RenderMaterial cpp, and to implement AddEntity NET code.

Comment: Or in this matter, I do not absolutely understand? ))